# concatenation? or how to to put mysql cell in 1 row

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm trying to find a way to put some cell in 1 row for google charts without the creation of a new table, if it's possible...

there is my case:

I got :

[image: my 'sensor' table]

I would like a result like :
date_time : tempsensor7 : tempsensor8 : tempsensor9 : humsensor7 : humsensor8 : humsensor9

I really appreciate some help... 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to do this for yourself yet? If so show us your attempt

Comment: Start by looking at `group_concat` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot tables are always kind of a bother in SQL.

```
SELECT date_time,
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 7 THEN temperature END) AS tempsensor7, 
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 8 THEN temperature END) AS tempsensor8, 
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 9 THEN temperature END) AS tempsensor9, 
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 7 THEN humidity END) AS humsensor7, 
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 8 THEN humidity END) AS humsensor8, 
  MAX(CASE sensor WHEN 9 THEN humidity END) AS humsensor9 
FROM NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions
GROUP BY date_time;
```

Comment: thank you, It's help me a lot. I have to modify my date_time column to remove second, but it's exactly what I was looking for!